# Starting intent from onPostExecute() method with a flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using the default **LoginActivity**, when you go to **New... > Android Activity** inside Eclipse with ADT Tools on Android 4.2 SDK.

It contains an email field, password field and a button that says "Sign in or Register". When you click on that button, it performs a fake async network request, calls a few methods to show progress bar, verify user login with dummy data, and the last thing that gets called if everything is successful:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                //finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                mPasswordView
                        .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }


}
```

I commented out finish(), and instead would like to open a new activity window that would be my main app window (Logged in state). I just started with Android yesterday, and I've seen a lot of examples use fragments for this sort of thing instead of activities. Does it matter? Anyway, it works fine, it opens a new activity but I can still press "Back button" and it will take me the *login screen*. I am pretty sure those flags I set below on the activity is what's required to clear the history stack, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix above code to clear the history stack? In other words after I log in, it should take me to the new activity, and if I press **Back**, it should take me to the *Home screen*.

### Update

I have attached code for LoginActivity, MainActivity, AndroidManifest.

**Link**: https://gist.github.com/sahat/5445657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead. The flags you are using create a new task but don't do anything to the rest of the stack. This flag will clear all other `Activities`. If the `Activity` exists, it will just clear out the rest of the `Activities` so the `MainActivity` will be on top

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

**Edit**

If you want to go to the Home screen after pressing back from the next `Activity` then just call `finish()` on the login `Activity` when you log in. This will remove the login page from your stack. You can also specify

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

in the `Activity` tag for login screen in `manifest`

Comment: Thank you I will try this right now. But on a related note: If I want to create a single activity app but with multiple views: loggedIn, loggedOut, settingsView, detailView, masterView...is fragments right approach for this?

Comment: Without knowing any more, I would say that `Fragments` would be a good fit. You also may want to check out [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Viewpager may not be what you want but worth checking out

Comment: I followed your suggestion but that still doesn't work. Same issue as before. I will update my question and post a code of MainActivity and LoginActivity on Github Gist.

Comment: I guess I don't follow what you want. You log in, at new activity, press back and go to login screen. Back again then home screen. Is this what you want and isn't happening?

Comment: Looks like option#1 is what I am after. I still want to have a history for other pages that are children of MainActivity, but not for LoginActivity. Thanks a lot! This should work, I'll try it in half hour.

Comment: If you set that flag in your `activity` tag then it won't effect your other `Activities` but calling finish()` is just as easy. It will run the `onDestroy()` method, clearing it from the stack. Ok, let me know if this is what you were after

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView
                    .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
```

}